# How to autocomplete citations in markdown files

Tags: filetype-tex, filetype-markdown

I take notes in markdown files which I sometimes convert to other documents with pandoc. With the  `--bibliography=bibliography.bib` argument, pandoc recognizes the `@key` citation format in markdown and adds the corresponding bibliographical reference at the end of the document. I would like to use some autocomplete menu to insert those citations based on the keys available in the bib file.

The [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/) plugin autocompletes citations based on a bibtex file. Would it be possible to do the same in markdown files?

Answer (score 3):

I hope it's OK to answer my question once again, the answer is easy once you know about the existence of the [vim-pandoc](https://github.com/vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc) plugin, but somehow I couldn't find it directly . I use [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim) to install plugins, added the following to my .vimrc:

```
" Markdown citation and syntax
Plugin 'vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc'
Plugin 'vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc-syntax'
" Disable folding of vim-pandoc plugin
let g:pandoc#modules#disabled = ["folding"]
```

Mention a bibliography file in the yaml front matter of the markdown file :

```
---
title: Reading notes
author: Author Name
bibliography: /path/to/references.bib
abstract: Reading notes with references
---
```

Then the vim-pandoc plugin can autocomplete `@key...` references with CTRL X CTRL O based on the keys in the bibliography.

It can look for the bibliography in other places and retrieve suggestions that match in any field using the bibtool program, see `:help vim-pandoc-bibliographies-module`.

Comment: Paul, it is absolutely ok to answer your own question. You can even accept your own answer, but only after 48 hours (maybe someone comes around with a better answer).

Comment: I have been trying to use vim-pandoc for this, but I get 'Omni completion (^O^N^P) Pattern not found' errors. Did you have to do anything else to get it working?

Comment: @twsh this error message is probably because vim cannot find your bibliography. Try a few differnt ways to specify the bibliography mentioned in  `:help vim-pandoc-bibliographies-module.`. If it still doesn't work, try to make a minimal vimrc that loads only `vim-pandoc` and ask a new question. Copy and paste your minimal `.vimrc` and minimal bibliography in the question so others can reproduce your error and help you.

Comment: @PaulRougieux It turns out that things are stranger than it simply not working. I asked a question here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/27809/vim-pandoc-bibliography-completion-works-only-when-writing-a-new-file-with-gvim