# vim-pandoc bibliography completion works only when writing a new file with GVim

Tags: autocompletion, plugin-vim-pandoc

I have installed [vim-pandoc](https://github.com/vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc), as suggested [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/26227/6909). When I open Vim in the terminal I get only 'Omni completion (^O^N^P) Pattern not found' errors. `echo pandoc#bibliographies#Find_Bibliographies()` returns a list of biblatex files, as expected.

One very strange thing is that if I open GVim and write a new .md file, completion works. But not if I then open the same file either from the terminal or with GVim.

I raised the issue [here](https://github.com/vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc/issues/377).

I have Vim 8.2.716 on Ubuntu 20.10.

Here is my .vimrc:

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

" pandoc
Plugin 'vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc'
Plugin 'vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc-syntax'
Plugin 'vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc-after'

" better LaTeX conceal, which pandoc will inherit
Plugin 'KeitaNakamura/tex-conceal.vim'

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
" To ignore plugin indent changes, instead use:
"filetype plugin on
"
" Brief help
" :PluginList       - lists configured plugins
" :PluginInstall    - installs plugins; append `!` to update or just :PluginUpdate
" :PluginSearch foo - searches for foo; append `!` to refresh local cache
" :PluginClean      - confirms removal of unused plugins; append `!` to auto-approve removal
"
" see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
" Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line

" UK spelling for Markdown
autocmd FileType markdown setlocal spell spelllang=en_gb

" recognise .md as Markdown
autocmd BufNewFile,BufReadPost *.md set filetype=markdown.pandoc

" case insensitive search
set ignorecase

" tabs are 4 spaces
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4

" omnicompletion
set omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete
set completeopt=menu,menuone

" conceal settings
set conceallevel=2
let g:tex_conceal="abdgm"

" look for bibliographies
let g:pandoc#biblio#sources="l"

" omnicomplete
set omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: this is a problem of that plugin. So the issue tracker is the right place to discuss this.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt This doesn't happen to everyone who uses the plugin. So, it's a problem of the interaction between the plugin and my setup.

Comment: [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I loaded just vim-pandoc. It makes no difference. (Assuming I followed the instructions correctly, of course.)

Comment: Yeah, this is a frustrating problem and it is not known exactly whether vim-pandoc does not see the `refs.bib` file or if something else is not working. @twsh - did you manage to solve the issue, please?

Comment: @r0berts I now use Neovim and a different config file. And it works. But I'm not sure how to draw any helpful conclusions from that.